# How to compare the value entered through input box

Tags: php

What's wrong with this code

```
$login=array('user'=>'abc','pwd'=>'123');
if($_POST['user']==$login['user'])&&($_POST['pwd']==$login['pwd'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `If` condition is wrong.Need to add whole `opening & closing braces`.

```
if( ($_POST['user']==$login['user'])&&($_POST['pwd']==$login['pwd']) )
```

Or even you can use like

```
if( $_POST['user']==$login['user'] && $_POST['pwd']==$login['pwd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with this..

`if($_POST['user']==$login['user'] && $_POST['pwd']==$login['pwd'])`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$login=array('user'=>'abc','pwd'=>'123');
if(($_POST['user']==$login['user']) && ($_POST['pwd']==$login['pwd']))
```

Comment: Some additional info, along with your answer would be great